# Check dictionary Key Contains

Tags: c#, key, contains

I have to store two key one value in dictionary. So that i am using like this.

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> dicThreatPurgeSummary = new Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,int>>();
```

I have added key, key and value.

```
Dictionary<int, int> innerdict = new Dictionary<int,int>();
innerdict.Add(Month, Count);
dicThreatPurgeSummary.Add(Group, innerdict);
```

i am able to view value like this

```
int a = dicThreatPurgeSummary[Group][Month];
```

I need to update the value for dicThreatPurgeSummary[Group][Month] if it already exists. Please help me to find out this.

Comment: Have you tried using the `TryGetValue` method of dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
if(dicThreatPurgeSummary.ContainsKey(Group) &&
   dicThreatPurgeSummary[Group].ContainsKey(Month))
{
    dicThreatPurgeSummary[Group][Month] = NewValue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Slightly more efficient than two calls to `ContainsKey` and three dictionary indexings:

```
Dictionary<int, int> forGroup;
if (dicThreatPurgeSummary.TryGetValue(Group, out forGroup) &&
    forGroup.ContainsKey(Month))
{
    forGroup[Month] = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dictionary<>.ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) to check if a key exists, so you would do it like this:

```
if (dicThreatPurgeSummary.ContainsKey(Group))
{
    if (dicThreatPurgeSummary[Group].ContainsKey(Month))
    {
        // dicThreatPurgeSummary[Group][Month] exists
    }
}
```

Note that it might be better to use a two dimensional *key* instead of cascading two dictionaries. That way you won’t need to care to add a new dictionary every time you use a new key for the first level, and you would have all values in the same dictionary, allowing you to iterate over the values or check for values existance.

You could use a [tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) for that:

```
var dicThreatPurgeSummary = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>();
dicThreatPurgeSummary.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(Group, Month), Count);

// accessing the value
int a = dicThreatPurgeSummary[new Tuple<int, int>(Group, Month)];

// checking for existance
if (dicThreatPurgeSummary.ContainsKey(new Tuple<int, int>(Group, Month)))
{
    // ...
}
```

#### Using a prettier subtype

*(untested)*

```
class IntIntDict<T> : Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, T>
{
    public T this[int index1, int index2]
    { get { return this[new Tuple(index1, index2)]; } }

    public bool ContainsKey (int index1, int index2)
    {
        return ContainsKey(new Tuple(index1, index2));
    }

    public void Add (int index1, int index2, T value)
    {
         Add(new Tuple(index1, index2), value);
    }
    // ...
}
```

And then you could just use it like this:

```
var dicThreatPurgeSummary = new IntIntDict<int>();
dicThreatPurgeSummary.Add(Group, Month, Count);

// accessing the value
int a = dicThreatPurgeSummary[Group, Month];

// checking for existance
if (dicThreatPurgeSummary.ContainsKey(Group, Month))
{
    // ...
```

}

Comment: On one level using Tuple makes sense, but you do end up with much uglier code.

Comment: if (dic.ContainsKey(Group) && dic[Group].ContainsKey(Month)) { ... }

Comment: @juharr You could probably make that prettier using some utility functions (extension methods) or even making a subtype of `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, T>` that has those directly (for example a `ContainsKey(int, int)` method).

Comment: Composing the two `int`s into a `long`, or even into a single `int`, might be even better than using a `Tuple`.

Comment: @Rawling Yeah, and if you go for a subtype, you could easily abstract those conversions away.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, int> innerDic = null;
bool isGroupPresent = dicThreatPurgeSummary.TryGetValue(Group, out innerDic);
if(isGroupPresent == false)
{
    //No entry for Group.
}
else
{
    int count;
    bool isMonthPresent = innerDic.TryGetValue(Month, out count);
    //Same as above
}
```